# How does Corda settle disputes?

Tags: corda

So I've been tasked with developing a POC for my company and have been learning about Corda. I think I understand the overview of Corda and a few details but I came across something that I don't quite understand. To illustrate, let's use the IOU example that the tutorial uses.

In that case, let's say I have two parties: Alice and Bob. Alice borrows $20 from Bob. This is correctly recorded in both their vaults and DB.

Now, let's say Bob is a bad actor and manually updates the information on his side (including associated hashes for the transaction) so that the transaction states that Alice borrowed $30 instead of $20.

So here are my questions:

1. Are there any safeguards built into Corda to prevent Bob from arbitrarily changing the data on his end?
2. If he is successful in mutating the facts on his end, how does the network decide who is correct in the future when Alice and Bob both present mutually exclusive transaction histories?
3. In a similar use case, imagine there is a fact that is initially shared between multiple parties, then is legitimately marked as only concerning one party, and then is again shared multiple (potentially different) parties. In this case, what would happen if the fact were to be illegitimately mutated during the single party access phase of the fact's lifespan?

Thanks in advance to all the people that help clear this up!

Answer (score 0):

This will be specified in the smart contract you setup with the counterparty when instigating the trade. Cobra will not settle your distributes since this defeats the whole purpose of the platform.